# Hadoop - java.library.path

Tags: opencv, hadoop, javacv

I'm trying to use hadoop for image/video processing, this is what I'm using:

- osx yosemite
- hadoop 2.7.1
- javacv 1.1 (https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv)

I did some tests locally and they worked fine, when I run the code in the pseudodistributed mode I get the error:

```
Error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_imgproc in java.library.path
```

I built the opencv libraries and copied them to the fs:

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal libs /user/me/libs
```

then I set the java.library.path:

```
conf.set( "mapred.child.java.opts" , "-Djava.library.path=/user/me/libs/");
```

When running the code I print the java.library.path and it is what I set, but the libraries are still not found.

Any idea of what is happening there? what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to copy the macosx-x86_64 jars to the fs, once I did that it worked correctly.